# Can I share a .ipa file (iOS app) among multiple users?

Tags: itunes, applications, sharing, accounts

Is it possible to share a .ipa file between iOS device users who have purchased the app? The reason is we do not want to download the app (especially if it has a large file size, like 1GB).

For example, User 1 has purchased 'Scrabble' and User 2 has also purchased 'Scrabble'. User 1 has a good internet connection and finished downloading. User 2 has a bad internet connection. In this case, User 2 would benefit by copying the .ipa file to his computer (if Apple allows). Since both users have purchased the application, it is not piracy or illegal.

I just don't have two accounts to try and I don't know where to look for the answer. Answers or a link to read would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

That's a really interesting question.

But first I give you another situation:
If user 2 wants to use an app already bought and downloaded by user 1, the only thing user 2 needs to do is add the .ipa file of that app in his iTunes and authorize his computer with the apple id of user 1. (in iTunes click on 'Store' > 'Authorize this computer')

If two people want to use the same app they don't need to both download the app. They don't even have to both purchase the app. They can share the .ipa file if they authorize each other's computers.

In the situation you present - where user 2 also bought the app but didn't download it - I think he would still need to authorize his computer with the apple id of user 1 in iTunes. That's because I think the identity (apple id) of the buyer/downloader of the app is stored in the .ipa file, but I'm not 100% certain about that.

Comment: The scenario you mentioned is officially described by Apple.
       
User1 and user2 in my scenario do not share the same Apple ID. They both have separate Apple ID. Their main concern is not price they have to pay but the download size and internet connection.

Comment: As I said earlier, in the second scenario, user 2 would still need to authorize the Apple ID of user 1 on his computer before syncing the .ipa file to his iOS device. I did a quick google search and found this: http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=531005     Read the 3rd last post. This leads me to believe I was right about the Apple ID of the buyer (user 1) being stored in the .ipa file.